# jquery traversing part of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

If I have a large form and want to traverse only part of it (elements inside `div#traverseMe`), what would be the best solution to do this. Here is an example form:

```
<form id="form1">
 <input type="text" name="text1" />
 <div id="traverseMe">
  <input type="text" name="text2" />
  <input type="text" name="text3" />
 </div>
</form>
```

I would like to get all (and only) FORM elements that are inside `traverseMe`. I am currently using a javascript function that loops through all children (`document.forms['form1'][i]`) of the form with the goal of transforming the form into XML, which is fine for the entirety of the form but overkill considering I only need a portion of it. Is there a suitable jQuery solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
$("#traverseMe > :input").each(function() {
  //do someting
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/v3scP/1/

Comment: I think adding `#form1` does not add much because an ID (`#traverseMe`) is unique anyway.

Comment: @pimvdb - thanks for pointing that out - answer changed accordingly.

Comment: This is brilliant and jsfiddle is very useful! My last question (and I have tried altering in jsfiddle) is how to test if the element is a radio button and checked, checking that it is a radio button is fine `if($(this).prop("type") == 'radio')` but checked didn't seem to work: `if($(this).prop("checked") == 'checked')`

Comment: `if($(this).prop("type") == 'radio' && $(this).prop("checked"))` should work. `prop` should return a "truthy" value.

Comment: I discovered that `attr` should be used instead: `if($(this).attr("checked") == 'checked')`. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mark Aroni: You could also use `$(this).is(":checked")`.

Comment: I did test `$(this).prop("checked")` for `'checked'` and `true` and neither worked initially, however after re-testing this does return `true`.

Comment: I ended up having to use `$("#traverseMe input")` as `$("#traverseMe > :input")` returned nothing in my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it's Id in the selector:

```
$('#traverseMe input').each(doStuff);
```

Or you can pass the context to the jQuery constructor:

```
var context = document.getElementById('traverseMe');
$('input', context).each(doStuff);
```

Comment: I like the ability to pass the context, I've not seen this before, thanks